# How to get the value of selected item inside datalist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My list is generated via php:

```
                    <input name="txt_name" list="emp_names" autocomplete="off" id="txt_name" class="textbox" onchange="getID(emp_names.text);"/>
                        <datalist id="emp_names">
                            <?php
                                $host = "localhost";
                                $user = "root"; 
                                $pass = "mark";
                                $db = "payrolldb";
                                $cons = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
                                mysql_select_db($db,$cons);
                                //query start
                                $query = "SELECT ID_Employee, CONCAT(LastName,', ',FirstName) AS Name, Department FROM tbl_employeeInfo;";
                                $result = mysql_query($query);
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo "<option value='".$row['Name']."'>".$row['ID_Employee']."</option>\n";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </datalist>
```

And it shows up like this.
[image]

Each of the options has a text value, which is "15" from the image.
the value of the option itself is "Mehta, Jack"

I wanted to know how to get the text value and to pass it from a javascript function.

I tried using an onchange method in both the input and the datalist tag.

But it says Cannot ready property text of 'undefined'.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ahh yes, I have yet to change my mysql connections, this is just to test whether my SQL statement is correct.

Comment: I'm planning to use mySQLi by the way.

Comment: Are you looking this http://plnkr.co/edit/fJ8aT1PsbftWV8Q6d0tZ?p=preview ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// get the input element and attach event listener to it
document.getElementById("txt_name").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) { // if enter/return key is pressed
        alert(this.value); // get the value
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Should I put this code in another function or just inside the <script>?

Comment: @MarkCortejo  just inside the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I have found to do this using JQuery

```
var selection = $("#txt_name").val();
var text = $("#emp_names option").filter(function () { return this.value == selection; }).text();
```

You have to put the function on the oninput event of the input NOT the datalist. This will fire as soon as you pick the selection. if you use onchange event it will only fire after you lose focus or the blur() happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to get `datalist option text` in javascript

You can add one more attribute `id` and put that text value there and get the result like below

**HTML**

```
    <input list="emp_names" id="txt_name">
    <datalist id="emp_names">
      <option value="Mehta, Jack1" id="15">15</option>
      <option value="Mehta, Jack2" id="16">16</option>
      <option value="Mehta, Jack3" id="17">17</option>
      <option value="Mehta, Jack4" id="18">18</option>
      <option value="Mehta, Jack5" id="19">19</option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="button" onclick="alertTheSelectedValue()" value="submit">
```

**JS**

```
     var alertTheSelectedValue = function() {
      var val = document.getElementById('txt_name').value;
      var text = $('#emp_names').find('option[value="' + val + '"]').attr('id');
      alert(text);
    }
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fJ8aT1PsbftWV8Q6d0tZ?p=preview