# How to get id of selected item in database populated combobox in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, database, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a problem regarding obtaining id from Combo Box populating name of customer from a database containing field id & name. I want to get the id of name selected by user from Combo Box. Following is the code i have applied to populating Combo Box:

```
    <input type="text" class="input-field" id="registerNumber" name="register_number" 
               list="register_number" placeholder="Select Register No" /></label>

<!-- Populating Editable ComboBox -->
    <datalist id="register_number" >
    <?php                               
        $result_set= mysqli_query( $connection, "Select  id,  customer_name from 
              service_register ");

       while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
            echo "<option value=\"{$result["customer_name "]}\" 
                          id=\"{$result["id"]}\"></option>";
        }   
?>
```

Comment: In order to assist you, May I ask what's your goal and what's exactly the problem is?

Comment: To get the answer of question please visit following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207121/how-to-get-the-value-of-selected-item-inside-datalist-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to set the type of the input to text and you should wrap the input with a form tag. The form tag will have the url of the server side code that will handle the form submission. A submit button should be provided for the user. For clarity you should visit this example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

```
<form action="server_code.php" method="get">
    <input class="input-field" id="registerNumber" name="register_number" 
                   list="register_number" placeholder="Select Register No" /></label>

    <!-- Populating Editable ComboBox -->
        <datalist id="register_number" >
        <?php                               
            $result_set= mysqli_query( $connection, "Select  id,  customer_name from 
                  service_register ");

           while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
                echo "<option value=\"{$result["customer_name "]}\" 
                              id=\"{$result["id"]}\"></option>";
            }   
    ?>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for for help I will correct my input box ... but my question is that I want to grab id of selected name in combo box. How  can i do it?

Comment: instead of this <option value=\"{$result["customer_name "]}\" 
                              id=\"{$result["id"]}\"></option> you should use this code       <option value="{$result["id"]}">{$result["customer_name "]}</option>. That way the id will be the value of the option and when it is selected it would be the value of register_number when the user submits the form